# How would you interpret the following innotop output?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb

I'm trying to optimize an application running a MySQL with the InnoDB storage engine.

When running `innotop` in the live environment I get the following output:

```
When   Load  QPS     Slow  QCacheHit  KCacheHit  BpsIn   BpsOut 
Now    0.00   87.80     0     41.21%    100.00%  11.51k  836.42k
Total  0.00  105.50   190     15.04%     99.34%  13.23k  692.85k
```

`When`, `Load`, `QPS` and `Slow` are self-explanatory.

But what about `QCacheHit`, `KCacheHit`, `BpsIn` and `BpsOut`? In general, what are considered "okay" values for those, and when should I start worrying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QCacheHit` is the percentage of the time that the [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html) is hit. `KCacheHit` is the percentage of the time that the [innodb buffer pool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html) is hit (similar to the [key buffer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-key-cache.html)). `BpsIn` is the number of bytes coming in to your server, `BpsOut` is the bytes out.

`QCacheHit` should be relatively high, if you're using the query cache. Your rates seem low. `KCacheHit` should also be relatively high, and you're in good shape.

`BpsIn/Out` don't really matter, unless you're trying to optimize the amount of data being sent/received by your server.

Answer (score 17):

Ratios are useless.  Seriously.  Just ignore them.
http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/28/why-you-should-ignore-mysqls-key-cache-hit-ratio/

Yeah, I'm the author of innotop.  I put those features in so people would stop asking me to.

From the article:

> Summary
>
> Major points in this article:
>
> - Counter ratios are meaningless as a performance analysis metric
>     because they are a) ratios of b) counters.
>
>   - You need to look at absolute magnitude, not ratios.
>   - For performance analysis, you need
>       to measure elapsed time, not just the number of times something
>       happens.
> - In the absence of timing information, and if you trust the cache’s
>     creator and assume that misses are more expensive than hits, then you
>     care about cache misses, not cache hits.
> - A Key_read is not guaranteed to be a random physical I/O, but it
>     might be. Gather Key_reads/Uptime over 10-second or 60-second
>     intervals and compare the results to your IO system’s capabilities.
> - MySQL doesn’t have good instrumentation for scientifically choosing
>     a key_buffer_size setting, but there are many unscientific approaches
>     that are better than ratio-based tuning.
> - Counter ratios suck for everything, not just for MyISAM tuning.
>
> I’ve had some heated arguments over these points, so I don’t expect
>   the above to pass without controversy. But really, it’s time to stop
>   with the bad advice about counter ratios. The sooner we do that, the
>   sooner we can move on to better things.